# Two equations in a block of table

Tags: tables, equations

[image]I make a table, 2*2，

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline

$F=ax$ &  \nabla F =a $         \\ \hline
$G=a+b\\ K=a+c$ &  $ H=c+d$

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

The above code generates mistakes.
In 2*1 block I want a 2 line equation. So I try `\align`,`\equation` and so on. For example,

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline

$F=ax$ &  \nabla F =a $         \\ \hline
\begin{align*}G&=a+b\\ K&=a+c\end{align*} &  $ H=c+d$

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

But this makes mistake too. So I have to use `$$`, but I do not know how to write two equation in `$$`.

Thank you. I am looking forward to your answer.

By the way, even this makes mistakes.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline

$F=ax$ &  \nabla F =a $         \\ \hline
\begin{equation*}G=a+b \end{equation*} &  $ H=c+d$

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Could you post an image (even handmade) of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @karlkoeller, yes, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I can not recognize your handwriting.

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
$ \begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
F(x) & G(x) \\
\hline
F(N) & G(N) \\
N=a & N=a \\
\hline
\end{array} $
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understand fully what you're trying to achieve since you refer to a 2x2 table in one place and a 2x1 table in another.

Since the contents of the table would appear to be math expressions, you may want to use an `array` instead of a `tabular` environment. For a 2x2 table you could proceed along the following lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
$ \begin{array}{|c|c|} 
\hline
F & \nabla F \\ 
\hline
G & \nabla G \\
\hline
\end{array} $
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ,Thank you very much for your answer. I want two equation in the block of the second row and the first and second column.

Comment: @Vivian - Do you mean you want the material in the cells be typeset in display style? If so, just insert `\displaystyle` at the beginning of the cells.

Comment: please see my picture. My poor non genuine English.